# How do you know what type of data a Dashing widget is listening for as argument?

Tags: dashing

Providing data to widgets is done in Ruby jobs using send_event(widget_id, json_formatted_data). As it seems each type of widget expects specific json format to process the data. For example, Meter Widget expects something like 
send_event('synergy',   { value: rand(100) })  while Number Widget expects something like send_event('valuation', { current: current_valuation, last: last_valuation }).

As Dashing is lightly documented, how do you know what json format to send to a specific widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer with some trial & error. Basically, you need to look at the .html file in the widget you are working with.

For example, Text Widget has the following elements

```
<h1 class="title" data-bind="title"></h1>
<h3 data-bind="text"></h3>
<p class="more-info" data-bind="moreinfo"></p>
```

This means you can use send_event with hash keys corresponding to the values set in data-bind attribute from the HTML. For example,

```
send_event('inst_alltime_total_runs', { text: "All Time Total Executions: " + $allTime[:total_executions] })
```